# How do I match a substring of variable length?

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2005

I am importing data into my SQL database from an Excel spreadsheet.

The `imp` table is the imported data, the `app` table is the existing database table.

`app.ReceiptId` is formatted as "A" followed by some numbers. Formerly it was 4 digits, but now it may be 4 or 5 digits.

Examples:

```
A1234
A9876
A10001
```

`imp.ref` is a free-text reference field from Excel. It consists of some arbitrary length description, then the ReceiptId, followed by an irrelevant reference number in the format " - BZ-0987654321" (which is sometimes cropped short, or even missing entirely).

Examples:

```
SHORT DESC A1234 - BZ-0987654321
LONGER DESCRIPTION A9876 - BZ-123
REALLY LONG DESCRIPTION A2345 - B
REALLY REALLY LONG DESCRIPTION A23456
```

The code below works for a 4-digit `ReceiptId`, but will not correctly capture a 5-digit one.

```
UPDATE app
SET
[...]
FROM imp
INNER JOIN app
ON app.ReceiptId = right(right(rtrim(replace(replace(imp.ref,'-',''),'B','')),5) 
                   + rtrim(left(imp.ref,charindex(' - BZ-',imp.ref))),5)
```

How can I change the code so it captures either 4 (A1234) or 5 (A12345) digits?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? I think some app.RecieiptId and imp.Ref will suffice. Also, should `A1234` be considered as equal to `A12345`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled No, each ReceiptId is unique. I'll add some sample data, but I thought it was fairly well described.

Comment: I would recommend not doing this in sql specially while doing a join.

Comment: SQL as a language isn't suited for ETL jobs, much less string parsing. SQL Server provides SSIS for this. You can import your Excel data, parse the column using a C# script (possibly with a Regex) and output the data to the target table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [ughai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4436237/ughai) rightfully wrote in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319459/sql-server-2005-how-do-i-match-a-substring-of-variable-length/30320096#comment48734356_30319459), it's not recommended to use anything other then columns in the `on` clause of a `join`.
The reason for that is that using functions prevents sql server for using any indexes on the columns that it might use without the functions.

Therefor, I would suggest adding another column to imp table that will hold the actual `ReceiptId` and be calculated during the import process itself.

I think the best way of extracting the `ReceiptId` from the `ref` column is using [`substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) with [`patindex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx), as demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27f52/9):

```
SELECT ref,
       RTRIM(SUBSTRING(ref, PATINDEX('%A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', ref), 6)) As ReceiptId 
FROM imp
```

**Update**
After the conversation with t-clausen-dk in the comments, I came up with this:

```
SELECT ref,
       CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[ ]A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9| ]%', ref) > 0
       OR PATINDEX('A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9| ]%', ref) = 1 THEN
           SUBSTRING(ref, PATINDEX('%A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9| ]%', ref), 6) 
       ELSE
           NULL
       END As ReceiptId 
FROM imp
```

[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df929/1)

This will return null if there is no match,
when a match is a sub string that contains A followed by 4 or 5 digits, separated by spaces from the rest of the string, and can be found at the start, middle or end of the string.

Comment: if the varchar is 'A1234A', it will still be considered valid. If your varchar doesn't contain valid data, it will compare from first character, Your RTRIM is also unnecessary,

Comment: If the varchar does not contain valid data, then the comparison should fail anyway, but thanks for the rtrim advice and the last space, I'll edit my answer to fix that.

Comment: if the varchar(REF) starts with 6 spaces and it is not valid, then once you compare and there are lots of empty varchars in ReceiptId, you will update them all

Comment: Example to illustrate that will return a row: SELECT
RTRIM(SUBSTRING(ref, PATINDEX('%A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', ref), 6))
FROM (SELECT '      ' REF) x
WHERE REF = ''

Comment: @t-clausen.dk See my edited answer. Thanks for looking for flaws, it helps me improve my sql.

Comment: I've decided to try and do it in SSIS when it imports the data. Getting errors with that too! Might ask another question...

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will remove all characters before the A[number][number][number][number] and take the first 6 characters after that:

```
UPDATE app
SET
[...]
FROM imp
INNER JOIN app
ON app.ReceiptId in 
  (
   left(stuff(ref,1, patindex('%A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][ ]%', imp.ref + ' ') - 1, ''), 5),
   left(stuff(ref,1, patindex('%A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][ ]%', imp.ref + ' ') - 1, ''), 6)
  )
```

When using equal, the spaces after is not evaluated

Comment: [I see your `patindex` is as big as mine... :-)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094012/quotes?item=qt0467008)